# Configure packages during unattended installation

Tags: installation, configuration, dpkg

When installing certain packages, configuration options are presented at the end of the installation. However, when doing an unattended installation, it seems that the default options are always chosen. Is there a way to specify the options that I want to be selected during an unattended install (perhaps via some sort of configuration option)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're looking to do what's called "preseeding". This preseeds the installer with the answers you want to the questions, Check out the documentation here:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation
- https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/appendix-preseed.html
- And check out the [preseed](/questions/tagged/preseed)tag here too.